# Tweepy in exe Failed to send request _ssl

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tweepy

Just normal:

```
s = api.update_with_media(tweetImage, status=m)
```

Works perfectly fine running as .py
but when I create a .exe using pyinstaller it's throwing

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Any idea?

Comment: the error message seems to be cut off.

Comment: That's all  "Exception, e: print e" is showing

Comment: hm... that's interesting. However, seems to be hard to debug. Look at what pyinstaller does internally (I suspect it calls py2exe somewhere), and make sure you tell it to use the right libssl .dll for your program -- most probably, python uses version A, but the generated .exe tries to load a different version B.

Answer (score 0):

- Check `certififi` is installed.
- Explicitly pass the path to ssl client certificate file to the `cert` argument http request.
- Also make sure you package your `pem` file as a data file in `pyinstaller`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around pyinstaller. I simply used pyinstaller secript.py --onefile. I don't know where to start in making a .py to add the cert